# Como permitir tag <script> no Slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, script, typescript

Olá, estou usando o carrossel Slick.js, e gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como permitir a tag  para aparecer no content do carrossel.

Demo do [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Exemplo de como eu quero usar:

Código do Slick padrão:

```
<div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>
```

Como eu quero usar:

```
<div class="your-class">
    <script type="text/template">your content</script>
    <script type="text/template">your content</script>
    <script type="text/template">your content</script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Pela documentação não compreende fazer assim, então não permite usar assim, é com `div` mesmo ...

Comment: Virgilio será que não existe uma maneira de mexer e editar?

Comment: Com certeza tem, mas ai é criar um novo pacote a ser feito